# Same results returned from MySQL - I know why but don't know solution

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to achieve: I am trying to create a filter which students can use to filter tutors on my website by level, gender or subject. To do this I have created check-boxes which when submitted as "ON" or checked a query is run to find tutors that fufill that criteria. I have used a while loop to check which check-boxes have been checked.

What is happening: The query is returning the right results but say a tutor teaches Maths and English then he will be returned to the results div twice. This is because the tutor fulfills both queries and is returned twice.

I don't know how to go about fixing this so thanks in advance and I'd appreciate all help, below is the relevant section of the HTML and PHP coding.

```
<form action="" method="get" >
  Name: 
    <input type="text" name="tutor_name"><br>
  Level:
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="gcse">GCSE
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="a_level">A Level<br>
  Gender:
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="male">Male
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="female">Female<br>
  Subject:
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="maths">Maths
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="science">Science
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="english">English<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Go!">
```

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['check'])){
  foreach($_GET['check'] as $check) {

  $check = mysql_query("SELECT `tutor_id` FROM `tutors` WHERE $check=1");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
    $tutor_data = tutor_data($row['tutor_id'], 'first_name','image','rating','bio','last_name');

    echo "<br><h3> " . $tutor_data['first_name'];
    echo " " . $tutor_data['last_name'];
    echo "</h3><br>" . $tutor_data['bio'];
    echo "<br>Rating: " . $tutor_data['rating']. "<br><br>";
    }
  }
    $number= mysql_num_rows($check);
      echo "<b>$number</b> results";
}
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @user2631669 Saw that so removed the comment. Your database structure seems a bit odd, if there's a new subject added, you'll need to change the structure.

Comment: always try to avoid running query in loop.

Comment: @Sebastien Yes doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(!empty($_GET['check'])){
  $chks = array(); //Declare Array
  foreach($_GET['check'] as $check) {
    $chks[] = "$check=1"; // Add 'checkboxvalue=1' to the array
  }
  $check = implode(' OR ',$chks); // Join the array with ' OR '
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT `tutor_id` FROM `tutors` WHERE $check");

    $number= mysql_num_rows($check);
      echo "<b>$number</b> results";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
    $tutor_data = tutor_data($row['tutor_id'], 'first_name','image','rating','bio','last_name');

    echo "<br><h3> " . $tutor_data['first_name'];
    echo " " . $tutor_data['last_name'];
    echo "</h3><br>" . $tutor_data['bio'];
    echo "<br>Rating: " . $tutor_data['rating']. "<br><br>";
    }

}
```

Here i am building up the `where` clause in the loop and executing single query.

Comment: YOUR A GENIUS A SUPER DUPER THANK YOU. Do you mind explaining the first 5 lines of code. From what I understand you have created an array called $chks and for each submitted get variable with the name CHECK the value of it is inserted into the array.

Comment: just created an array `$chks` and store the checkbox items there. eg: if you have `maths` and `english` checked the array will be `$chks=array('maths=1', 'english=1')` then i join this array with ` OR ` so the string becomes `maths=1 OR english=1` and becomes a nice where condition.

Comment: add outside the foreach `$toCheck = array('gcse'=>1, 'a_level'=>1, 'male'=>1, 'female'=>1, 'maths'=>1, 'science'=>1, 'english'=>1);`

add inside the foreach `if($toCheck[$check]) ...`

Answer (score 1):

What you should have is a single query that simple checks for multiple values at once:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
WHERE 1 in (maths, english, male, a_level)
```

Right now you're running multiple queries independently of each other, so it stands to reason you'll get a duplicate tutor for every tutor that has two or more of the attributes you're searching for. If you can't rewrite to the single-query model, then you'll have to fetch the results of each individual query, then combine them in PHP to filter out the dupes.

Also, note that your query as written is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Do not use that code on a production system until you've fixed this problem.

Comment: Tried this and doesn't work: $check_query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `tutor_id` FROM `tutors` WHERE 1 in $check");. Also how is my code vulnerable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `http://example.com/foo.php?check=; DROP TABLE STUDENTS --`. I sincerely hope little Bobby Tables isn't one of your students/clients... read the site I linked to.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of this problem. I shall read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `tutor_id` FROM `tutors` WHERE $check=1 GROUP BY `tutor_id`");
```

EDIT:

Or maybe a `SELECT DISTINCT...` could work

Comment: Tried before they don't work because the queries are independent of each other. Thanks anyway